# Запрос данных на стороне сервера, а не клиента (react + redux + isomophic)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend

Всем привет! Только начинаю изучать react и подвис на элементарной (вроде бы) штуке.
Ситуация: Есть форма авторизации (логин + пароль). Пользователь их вводит, данные уходят на API, приходит токен доступа (OAuth 2.0) и идентификатор аутентифицированного пользователя. Далее пользователя редиректит на профиль (редирект полный, срабатывает нода). Отображается страница без информации пользователя, а через пару минут данные о нем загружаются и страница переписовывается уже так, как должно быть.

Примерный код страницы такой:

```
class Page extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        user: null,
        error: null
    };

    const api = new Api(this.props.store);

    if (!this.props.store.access.success) {
        console.log('Пользователь не авторизован');
    } else {
        // Запрашиваем информацию о пользователе
        api.userInfo(this.props.store.access.user_id).then((response) => {
            if (response.code === 0) {
                this.setState({
                    user: response.items[0]
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    error: response.message
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

render() {
    if (this.state.user === null) {
        return <div>Информация о пользователе не доступна</div>;
    }

    return ( /* Здесь генерируется информация на основе данных пользователя */ );
}
}
```

В принципе, все работает, но не так, как хотелось бы. Подскажите как организовать загрузку данных ДО выдачи ее клиенту (то есть на стороне сервера на ноде). Спасибо

Comment: а разве не логично сначала сделать все что хотите и только после этого отдавать на клиент?

Comment: Логично. Так и хочу, собственно =)

Comment: То есть Вы знаете как надо, но не знаете как это сделать? Или Вы уже поняли и вопрос больше не актуален?

Comment: Да, принцип я понимаю. Судя по идеологии "изоморфного приложения", 90% кода будет и серверным и клиентским. Я реализовал загрузку данных через API. На клиенте это работает, на сервере нет. Я не могу понять как заставить сервер сначала собрать все данные, а потом отдать готовую страницу.

Answer (score 0):

По идеологии `react` реакт-компонент, это точка входа логики представления.

Запросы к `api`, это не логика представления, поэтому ей не место в реакт-компонентах.

Раз уж Вы используете `redux`, то нужно помнить что запросы к чему-либо как и вся логика не относящияся к представлению должны быть сконцентрирована в `action-creator`. Ведь именно логическая декомпозиция позволяет производить действия не затрагивая другие части-слои программы. Конкретно в Вашем случаи Вы сможете загрузить все что Вам нужно до рендера  компонентов реакт.

Поэтому в момент выполнения server side роута первым делом Вы должны создать-получить нужное Вам состояние и только после этого производить рендер реакт-приложения. Для этого как минимум нужно при создании приложения продумывать его так чтобы `action-creator` не противоречили логики друг друга и выполняли исключительно одну задачу. Вы должны, как создатель, должны знать в какой момент Ваше приложения считается работоспособным и именно в этот момент Вы должны посылать "какое-то событие" и именно на это событие Вы должны подписывать `store` на сервере и по этому событию производить рендер реакт-приложения.

И хоть Вы и используете `redux` это будет верно для всего, ведь вынос логики в отдельный слой позволит Вам загрузить и распарсить нужные для работы приложения данные не прибегая к рендеру реакт-приложения. Так же этот подход верен не только относительно реакта, ведь подобная архитектура   существовала задолго до реакта и зарекомендовала себя как наилучшая.